# Find previous <p> after nth character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I want to create a "Read more" button that appears if an elements contains over 1700 characters.

I have achieved this as such:

```
 var textlength = $(this).text().length;

  if(textlength > 1700){
    $(this).html($(this).html().substring(0, 1700));
    $(this).append(readmorelink);
  };
```

This removes all characters after the 1700th. But I would like to remove characters from the 1700th and back to the last `</p>` tag.

Does anyone know how I can traverse back from an nth character to a specific element?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvWcH/

Comment: Can you show some sample html

Comment: a jsfiddle would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lastIndexOf` method to find the last occurance of a string before a specific index in the string:

```
var text = $(this).html();
var index = text.lastIndexOf('</p>', 1700);
$(this).html(text.substring(0, index + 4));
```